# xhprof-html won't show Run Report (No XHProf runs specified in the URL)

Tags: php, wordpress, profiling, xhprof

How do I show the Run Report for a given xhprof run using `xhprof-html`?

I installed [tideways-xhprof](https://github.com/tideways/php-xhprof-extension).

```
apt-get install php-dev
git clone "https://github.com/tideways/php-xhprof-extension.git"
cd php-xhprof-extension
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

I enabled it in my `php.ini`

```
extension=/usr/lib/php/20190902/tideways_xhprof.so
```

I [configured wordpress to write-out xhprof runs](https://pressjitsu.com/blog/profiling-wordpress-performance/) in my `wp-config.php` file

```
# PHP profiling with tideways-xhprof 
#  * https://pressjitsu.com/blog/profiling-wordpress-performance/
if ( isset( $_GET['profile'] ) && $_GET['profile'] === 'secret-string' ) {
    tideways_xhprof_enable( TIDEWAYS_FLAGS_MEMORY + TIDEWAYS_FLAGS_CPU );
    register_shutdown_function( function() {
        $results = tideways_xhprof_disable();
        file_put_contents( '/path/to/my/xhprof/dir/' .date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', time() - date('Z')). '.xhprof' , serialize( $results ) );
    });
}

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

And I was successfully able to dump-out xhprof files by visiting https://example.com/index.php?profile=secret-string

```
root@host:/path/to/my/xhprof/dir/# du -sh *
1,6M    2022-05-25T18:15:45Z.xhprof
1,6M    2022-05-25T18:18:38Z.xhprof
root@host:/path/to/my/xhprof/dir/#
```

I also created a website with [xhprof-html](https://github.com/phacility/xhprof). And I [configured it](https://github.com/phacility/xhprof/blob/0bbf2a2ac34f495e42aa852293fe0ed821659047/xhprof_lib/utils/xhprof_runs.php#L100-L104) to find the above `.xhprof` files

```
root@host:/var/www/xhprof/xhprof-html# diff index.orig.php index.php 
83c83
< $xhprof_runs_impl = new XHProfRuns_Default();
---
> $xhprof_runs_impl = new XHProfRuns_Default( '/path/to/my/xhprof/dir' );
root@host:/var/www/xhprof/xhprof-html#
```

Now I can load access the `xhprof-html/index.php` file and it successfully displays my two `.xhprof` files at https://xhprof.example.com/xhprof-html/index.php

```
No XHProf runs specified in the URL.

Existing runs:

    2022-05-25T18:18:38Z.xhprof 2022-05-25 18:18:38
    2022-05-25T18:15:45Z.xhprof 2022-05-25 18:15:45
```

And if I click on either one, I'm redirected (as expected) to either of these pages:

- https://xhprof.example.com/xhprof-html/index.php?run=2022-05-25T18:18:38Z&source=xhprof
- https://xhprof.example.com/xhprof-html/index.php?run=2022-05-25T18:15:45Z&source=xhprof

However, [I would expect](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/profiling-drupal-8-sites-drupal-vm-xhprof-and-tideways) the above pages to render the actual `Run Report`. But they do not. Instead, I just see

```
No XHProf runs specified in the URL.

Existing runs:

    2022-05-25T18:18:38Z.xhprof 2022-05-25 18:18:38
    2022-05-25T18:15:45Z.xhprof 2022-05-25 18:15:45
```

Hello? **The XHProf run is clearly specified in the URL.**

How do I get `xhprof-html` to display the actual `Run Report`?

Comment: See also https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/139482/xhprof-html-wont-show-run-report-no-xhprof-runs-specified-in-the-url

Comment: See also https://serverfault.com/questions/1101860/xhprof-html-wont-show-run-report-no-xhprof-runs-specified-in-the-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Run Report` is not shown because it can't read the file.

### Problem

You are generating the file using the tideways xhprof and writing a serialized output to a file

- https://github.com/tideways/php-xhprof-extension

```
$results = tideways_xhprof_disable();
file_put_contents( '/path/to/my/xhprof/dir/' .date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', time() - date('Z')). '.xhprof' , serialize( $results ) );
```

([source](https://pressjitsu.com/blog/profiling-wordpress-performance/))

But then, you switch to hosting an older (no longer maintained) fork of xhprof to serve `xhprof_html` in your web server's document root

- https://github.com/phacility/xhprof

> Note: Of course you have to do this, and even the tideways docs link you to the `phacility` repo. The tideways repo itself curiously does *not* include the `xhprof_html` directory, possibly because tideways is a business that sells xhprof visualization SaaS -- so they stripped the "poor man's" `xhprof_html` from the fork of xhprof that they maintain

If you want to *read* the file using `XHProfRuns_Default()` then you should *write* the file using `XHProfRuns_Default()`.

#### Solution

Change the block in your `wp-config.php` to the following

```
# PHP profiling with tideways-xhprof 
#  * https://pressjitsu.com/blog/profiling-wordpress-performance/
if ( isset( $_GET['profile'] ) && $_GET['profile'] === 'secret-string' ) {
   tideways_xhprof_enable( TIDEWAYS_FLAGS_MEMORY + TIDEWAYS_FLAGS_CPU );
   register_shutdown_function( function() {
      $results = tideways_xhprof_disable();
      include_once( '/var/www/xhprof/xhprof_lib/utils/xhprof_runs.php' );
      $XHProfRuns = new XHProfRuns_Default( '/path/to/my/xhprof/dir' );
      $XHProfRuns->save_run( $results, date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z', time() - date('Z')) );
   });
}
```

Then generate a new profile

- https://example.com/index.php?profile=secret-string

You'll now see a new item named something like `62906fb2c49b4.2022-05-27T06:29:06Z.xhprof`

```
No XHProf runs specified in the URL.

Existing runs:

    62906fb2c49b4.2022-05-27T06:29:06Z.xhprof 2022-05-27 06:29:06
    2022-05-25T18:18:38Z.xhprof 2022-05-25 18:18:38
    2022-05-25T18:15:45Z.xhprof 2022-05-25 18:15:45
```

Click this new item, and you'll acctually see the `Run Report` now that it can read the xhprof file format.

- https://xhprof.example.com/xhprof-html/index.php?run=62906fb2c49b4&source=2022-05-27T06:29:06Z

For more info on this issue, see:

- https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/2022/06/07/wordpress-xhprof/